# Cloned git repository in WSL2 keeps disappearing. Why is that?

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu, gitlab, wsl-2

I have cloned a git repository, from Gitlab, in WSL2, using the Ubuntu distribution, and when I start up the WSL2 on another time it is gone.

Can anybody tell me why this could happen?

Answer (score 1):

There is an ongoing issue related to [WSL2 and files disappearing](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4974)

It can depend on your OS (W10? Which version? W11?) and if you have applied the latest Windows updates.

Check first `%APPDATA%/Local/Packages/` if you see your files (before restarting WSL2).

And check, as in [issue 6221](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/6221), if `rootfs` is still visible.
For instance: `:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs`
But, as [NotTheDr01ds](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11810933/notthedr01ds) comments, that would be WSL1 only.

For WSL2, see [`microsoft/WSL` issue 4699 "WSL 2 should automatically release disk space back to the host OS"](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4699).

Comment: Note that the `rootfs` directory is only applicable to WSL1.  Under WSL2, the filesystem is in a virtual disk (`ext4.vhdx`) instead.  I know that Github issue references `rootfs`, but I think they were confused (remembering it from the WSL1 days, since WSL2 hadn't been out that long at that point).

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds Thank you. Good point. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

After doing a git clone, I am finding that the directory is empty. This seems to only happen if I ran git clone from a bash script.

I also discovered that doing "cd ." fixed the current instance of the problem and the files show up. A bit of a pain to always have to do this. Unfortunately adding this command to the script doesn't help. You have to type it in at the bash prompt.

Hope this workaround helps.

Michael Milette